# Umbraco : Footer Menu True/False Property

Tags: menu, umbraco, footer

I've tried adding a simple footer menu to umbraco6 using a new property showInFooter (True/False) on the doc type Textpage.

Creating the xslt file with the below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/descendant-or-self::node/node [string(data[@alias='ShowInFooter']) = '1']">
                <li>                    
                    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Added the macro to my masterpage:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="mgzFooterNavigation" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

And I've obviously ticked true on the pages I want in the footer menu, but I get no menu items :-/.

But I just get a blank `<ul> </ul>.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a blank `<ul> </ul>` that suggests that your xsl:for-each is not matching anything - you could test this by just outputting anything within the for-each using `xsl:value-of`.

So I guess your select in the for-each has a bug.

The two most likely bugs are that you've mis-spelled 'ShowInFooter' (does it have an initial lowercase letter - Umbraco does ususally default to one).

Secondly are your footer nodes ever in play?

From Umbraco's wiki (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Various_useful_XSLT_methods_in_Umbraco) you'd use this to run round the nodes under home (... and you'd replace 'myDocType' with the doctype of the home node assuming your nav is all nested underneath the home node)

```
xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//node [@nodeTypeAlias='myDocType']"
```

You could then verify that you're running round the right nodes using a `xsl:value-of`.

Then to extend using your field value it's something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//node [@nodeTypeAlias='myDocType']">
<xsl:variable name="footerItem" select="node[data[@alias='showInFooter'] = '1'">
<xsl:if test="$footerItem">
  <li>                    
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName" />
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get amelvin's answer to work in Umbraco 6. This is my attempt which works for me but might not for my setup.

```
<xsl:variable name="allNodes" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::root//umbTextpage[@isDoc]"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<ul class="footer-menu">
    <xsl:for-each select="$allNodes">
        <xsl:if test="showInFooter = 1"> 
            <li>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>

</xsl:template>
```